# Installing nodejs 0.10.36 on Ubuntu Trusty 64

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, vagrant, ansible, apt-get

How to do it, exactly?

I usually go this way:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

But it gives me only 0.10.33. Using apt-get is preferable way for me as I set it up with ansible and want some degree of compartability so bash script like

```
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v${NODE_VERSION}/${NODE_DIST}.tar.gz
tar xvzf ${NODE_DIST}.tar.gz
sudo rm -rf /opt/nodejs
sudo mv ${NODE_DIST} /opt/nodejs

sudo ln -sf /opt/nodejs/bin/node /usr/bin/node
sudo ln -sf /opt/nodejs/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm
```

would be the latest resort.

I run it locally on VirtualBox with Vagrant image ubuntu/trusty64.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about using `n`?

n is a version manager for node.js, it allow to have several version installed (And it install them for you), and to run a script with the version you want.

You can do:  `npm install -g n`
And then,    `n 0.10.36`
Or if you want the last version    `n latest`
Or the last stable:      `n stable`.

Comment: Solves the problem. For ansible guys, you can use

https://github.com/ansible-playbooks/n-node

as an example